# GLIBC_2.14 Error Message when Installing Pygrib

Tags: python, glibc

Trying to install pygrib via Anaconda package to a remote server. Instillation seems to have worked fine and all supporting libraries have been installed. But when I try to "import pygrib" I receive this message:

ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lustre/gporter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/../../libgrib_api-1.10.4.so)

I attempted to update GLIBC to the newest version, but I suspect the problem is hardwired in somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I attempted to update GLIBC to the newest version

What version did you end up with after the update?

Chances are, it's a version *older* than `2.14` (or you wouldn't be having this problem).

Note that *in general* a given distribution, e.g. Ubuntu-14.10, will *not* update the version of GLIBC *ever*. This is because GLIBC has a potential to break applications, and the distribution doesn't want to re-test *all* applications that ever shipped for it.

What you must do is either find a package for *your* distribution, or update the entire OS.

It's also possible to install newer GLIBC in non-default location, but this is not trivial, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains.